# Can I deploy an old ink! v3.x contract on the latest version of substrate/polkadot (pallet-contracts >= polkadot-v0.9.37)?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, ink, substrate-contracts-node, pallet-contracts

I have old smart contracts written in `ink! v3.x`, and I need to update the substrate version (including `pallet-contracts`) to `>= polkadot-v0.9.37`. After the update, I'll need to redeploy my smart contract again.

My question is, can I just compile and deploy the smart contract from old `v3.x` sources, or is it required to migrate it to `v4.x` at first in order to deploy it on `pallet-contracts >= polkadot-v0.9.37` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy old ink! contracts to newer versions of `pallet-contracts`. The pallet is backwards compatible.

Note that you will have to use a `cargo-contract` version from before 2.0:

```
cargo install cargo-contract --version 1.5 --force
```

The 2.0 version of `cargo-contract` is incompatible with ink! 3.x contracts.